# django models database schema

Tags: python, sql, django, database, django-models

In Django, how would a database schema look like for a social media site like Instagram? For example, how would you make it so that one user can post multiple posts, and they can only have 1 profile?

- I want to know what different tables I should have
- I want to know how I would connect the tables
- I want to know what I should write to link profile to posts(i.e. Foreign Key)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for profiles you add the user as a OneToOneField :

```
class Profile(models.model):
 User=models.OneToOneField ()

 Phone = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)
 Zip_code=models.IntegerField(default='')
 image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='users_photos',)
```

and for post you add the user as a foreign key:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  User=models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   )
  ....and some other fields you want to add
```